# Timeout wrapper for non-async method behaves inconsistently when large(ish) quantities are used in a loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core-3.1

I am using a third-party library that is non-async but can also either take longer than desired or occasionally completely block indefinitely (until cleared externally).

Represented for testing with this:

```
SlowWorkerResult SlowWorker(int i)
{
    var delay = i % 2 == 0 ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    return new SlowWorkerResult();
}

class SlowWorkerResult 
{
    
}
```

To handle these timeouts I wrap the call in a `Task.Run` and apply an extension method I wrote to it:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task<T> TimeoutAfter<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        var result = await Task.WhenAny(task, delayTask);
        if (result == delayTask)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        return await task;
    }
}
```

This works reliably whenever it is run individually, i.e.

```
async Task<(bool, int)> BigWorker(int i)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"BigWorker Started - {i}");
        
        //do some async work
        await Task.CompletedTask;

        //do some non-async work using the timeout extension
        var slowWorkerResult = await Task.Run(() => SlowWorker(i)).TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        //do some more async work
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        
        return (true, i);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (false, i);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"BigWorker Finished - {i}");
    }
}
```

*I am aware that this essentially abandons a thread*. Barring support from the third-party library that isn't coming any time soon (if ever), I have no other way to protect against a deadlock.

However, when I run a `BigWorker` in a parallel loop, I get unexpected results (namely that some sessions timeout when I would otherwise expect them to complete). For example, if I set `totalWorkers` to 10, I get an even split of success/failure and the process takes about 3 seconds as expected.

```
async Task Main()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    const int totalWorkers = 10;
    
    var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task<(bool, int)>>();
    Parallel.For(0, totalWorkers, i => tasks.Add(BigWorker(i)));
            
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    sw.Stop();
    
    var success = results.Count(r => r.Item1);
    var fails = results.Count(r => !r.Item1);
    var elapsed = sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"ss\.ffff");

    Console.WriteLine($"Successes: {success}\nFails: {fails}\nElapsed: {elapsed}");
}
```

Setting `totalWorkers` to a larger number, say 100, generates an essentially random number of success/fails with the total time taking much longer.

I suspect this is due to task scheduling and threadpools, however I can't figure out what I would need to do to remedy it. I suspect a custom task scheduler that would somehow make sure my `DoWork` wrapped task and my `Task.Delay` are executed at the same time. Right now it appears that the `Task.Delay`'s are occasionally being started/completed before their corresponding `DoWork` wrapped task.

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET Core and later or .NET Framework?

Comment: Added tag, targeting .Net Core 3.1

Comment: These questions might be relevant: [.NET Core equivalent to Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort) and also [Thread or Task (stopping a hung single line of code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087774/thread-or-task-stopping-a-hung-single-line-of-code). The second is related to the .NET Framework, but the `RunInterruptible` method runs on the .NET Core as well. The `RunAbortable` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect this is due to task scheduling and threadpools

Yes; specifically, the thread pool has a limited injection rate for new threads. If you need to pile on a bunch of synchronous work, then you should increase [this threshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), which will cause the thread pool to quickly inject up to that threshold and switch to the limited injection rate past that threshold.

Alternatively, you could do the timeout from *within* the `Task.Run`, but that's pretty complex.

Side notes:

- The `CancellationTaskSource` in `TimeoutAfter` doesn't do anything.
- `TimeoutAfter` can be replaced with [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) in .NET 6 and newer.
- The `Parallel.For` isn't doing anything useful; it's just parallelizing the *adding* of tasks to the concurrent collection (and the tiny amount of code at the beginning of `BigWorker`).