# CancellationToken - throw exception from Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, cancellation-token

I'm calling Class Library method within WPF app, using `CancellationToken`. Method exports data to Excel from Oracle, and sometimes operation takes too long or doesn't complete, so I tried with implementing cancellation.

WPF app - button click for export and export method:

```
public async void Export_Execute(object parameter)
{
    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
       InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(
           Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).ToString(),
       Filter = "Excel |*.xlsx",
       Title = "Save as"
    };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if (await Task.Run(() => GetData(dialog.FileName, DateTime.Now)))
        {
            var m = MessageBox.Show("Export complete, wish to open Excel file?",
                "Export", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

            if (m == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                Process.Start(dialog.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GetData` method:

```
public bool GetData(string _filename, DateTime? _date)
{
   try
   {
      using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
      {
         con.Open();

         MyTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

         OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MySchema.Employees", con)
         {
              CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
         };
         cmd.Parameters.Add("date_in", OracleDbType.Date).Value = _date;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.RefCursor,
             ParameterDirection.Output);
 
         var export = new MyExports();

         export.Export_DataReader(cmd, MyTokenSource.Token);

         return true;
      }
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Operation cancelled by user.", "Export data")
      return false;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     return false;
   }
}
```

If something goes wrong in this WPF method, I want an actual error displayed. But If user cancels `GetData` method manually, I want to display a predefined message.

C# Class library code:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer CancelExport { get; set; }

public void Export_DataReader(OracleCommand _cmd, CancellationToken? _cancel)
{
    //Doing long operations here for exporting to Excel...
    // Timer gets enabled here too - in more or less beginning of the code...

    Monitor(_cmd, _cancel);
}

private void Monitor(OracleCommand _cmd, CancellationToken? _cancel)
{
    if (_cancel != null)
    {
        CancelExport = new System.Timers.Timer();

        CancelExport.Elapsed += (sender, e) => MonitorEvent(sender, e, _cmd, _cancel);

        CancelExport.Interval = 2000;
        CancelExport.Enabled = true;
    }

}

private static void MonitorEvent(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e, OracleCommand _cmd,
    CancellationToken? _cancel)
{    
    if (_cancel.Value.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        CancelExport.Enabled = false;

        // When uncommented, this successfully returns Oracle exception
        // Leaving like this, code just goes through,
        // It ignores ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        // _cmd.Cancel();

        //This doesn't return OperationCancelledException to WPF App so
        //code keeps running like no error happened, even though error 
        //is visible in Output window                
        _cancel.Value.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

So, when I hit `MyTokenSource.Cancel()` in WPF app, I get Oracle.DataAccess.dll error exception If I want, but not `OperationCancelledException` from `CancellationToken`.

**What should I do to get `OperationCanceledException` back to my WPF app method?**

Comment: Are you looking for `MyTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);`? E.g. `MyTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);` to wait 1 second before cancellation

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, no I just simply want to throw back OperationCancelledException when user cancels TokenSource.

Comment: Could you include in the question the calling site of the `GetData` method? I assume it's an event handler of a UI control.

Comment: `//Doing long operations here for exporting to Excel...` -- Are these the operations that take too long or don't complete? If yes, then what is the purpose of placing the call `Monitor(_cmd, _cancel);` **after** these long-running operations?

Comment: What is the `MyTokenSource`? Is it a field of the enclosing class? Could you include its definition?

Comment: Where is `GetData` called? And where does `export.Export_DataReader` throw? Your code sample is a mess.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @mm8, It's hard to create a testable programme for this. It's a OpenXML library for Excel exports. I pass OracleCommand to it, and meanwhile things get prepared for Excel (creating file, autofit, styles, executing OracleCommand to get data and write it directly in Excel etc.) I started Timer to be able to cancel everything if export takes too long (time consuming queries). That's It. And as I mentioned in answer, Oracle .dll successfully returns errors (if any) from Timer.Elapsed, but CancellationToken's OperationCancelledException is swallowed, no matter how many try/catch blocks there are.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, **MyTokenSource** is a static (global) property which I use in WPF app, nothing more.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, sorry for bad code commenting. **Monitor** method is placed within long consuming operations. It's an OpenXML library for Excel, where you first need to create file from stream, and then all other things - styles, autofit, write data directly to .xslx...Code for that is just too long to post. Timer is supposed to monitor if user wants to cancel export, and If he does, then a lot of things need to be done (close stream + delete file, close OracleCommand etc.). But bottom line is that timer needs to throw OperationCancelledException back, so that app wil know.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, see my edited question for **GetData** method. You assumed correctly, It's a button click event.

Comment: So my understanding now is that the desirable behavior is to enable canceling of the long-running operation only at the points where the `Monitor` calls are placed. This means that in case a code fragment between two `Monitor` calls takes too long, the cancellation will be delayed accordingly, correct? Also you mentioned in the question that sometimes the operation **doesn't complete**. This means that in this case the cancelation will not have any effect, and the program will get stuck forever. Please confirm that this is the desirable behavior.

Comment: I assume that you are aware that the .NET cancellation infrastructure supports only cooperative cancellation, and the support for non-cooperative cancellation (`Thread.Abort`) has been dropped in .NET Core and later. Please confirm that the cancellation model that you are trying to implement is strictly cooperative. Otherwise please state explicitly in the question that you are aiming at interrupting abruptly  the long-running operation in a non-cooperative fashion.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, not exactly. **Monitor** is placed only once, in the beginning of  processes for Excel. Point of Timer is to be able to monitor whole time of export, and cancel it whenever. I can go other way explaining - I could add a lot of **_cancel.Value.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()** lines in my library code and things would get working, but It's not completely perfect. For example, sometimes .ExecuteReader is time consuming, so It could take even a minute when code would hit another **_cancel.Value.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()**.So I need a mechanism to cancel **GetData** instantly.

Comment: *"I need a mechanism to cancel `GetData` instantly."* -- This can mean either of two things 1) you want to forget the `GetData` invocation. The `GetData` will keep running, but your program will forget about it, and will pretend that nothing is happening. The user could click the button again, initiating a second `GetData` concurrently with the old forgotten one. Or 2) you want to terminate/kill/abort the `GetData` invocation immdiately in a non-cooperative fashion. Both options stink, but please clarify which one you prefer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, option 2 is desired output. Let me explain in real world scenario: To complete export I need to fetch data from DB (OracleCommand with DataReader.ExecuteReader) and create .xlsx file in OpenXML (SAX method, direct xml file manipulation). Now, when I try to do opposite - cancel all, I face bunch of problems: terminate query in DB (command.Cancel), close stream of created .xlsx file that we created and were writing in, and then delete it. Magic of that is actually in **Export_DataReader**, where I call my **Monitor**. But code for posting is too long.

Comment: Related questions: [.NET Core equivalent to Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort) and also [Thread or Task (stopping a hung single line of code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087774/thread-or-task-stopping-a-hung-single-line-of-code). The recommended way for implementing non-cooperative cancelation in .NET is to run the code on a separate process, and kill the process to cancel the code.

Comment: Btw the intention to implement non-cooperative cancellation is currently totally obfuscated in your question. This is the most important information that the question should contain, and should be placed prominently and unambiguously in the first paragraphs. Currently this intention is hidden in the comments. The comments can be removed at any time by a moderator, and nobody should be required to read them before answering a question. Please consider updating the question with this critical information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using creating separate cancellation token sources, one that [cancels automatically after a delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-timespan)), and one for the user to press and use [CreateLinkedTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=net-7.0) to combine them:

```
var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(42));
var manualCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutCts.Token, manualCts.Token);
try
{
    await DoAsyncOperation(linkedCts.Token);
}
// Or catch(Exception) if some other exception type if thrown
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    if (manualCts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Handle manual cancel
    }
    else if(timeoutCts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // handle timeout
    }
}
```

This should give you a way to determine what caused the cancellation.

> What should I do to get OperationCanceledException back to my WPF app method?

This is up to the library. Well designed libraries should throw `OperationCanceledException` when cancelled, but not all libraries are well designed. The fallback is to catch whatever exception type is thrown, or just all exceptions, and check if the cancellationTokens are triggered.

Comment: I will try, but don't see how this would help me. I thinik the problem is that token exception simply gets swallowed by timer. That's why I posted Oracle error too - which doesn't get swallowed.

Comment: @Lucy82 Sorry, missed the last bit of the question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I've tried using your answer, and It actually does work:)