# How forcefully end Parallel.Invoke loop?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, .net-7.0, cancellation, parallel.invoke

Inside the `Compute` function there are heavy, long-lasting calculations (dozens of minutes). I can't edit this function, I don't have access to the source code.

```cs
List<Action> parallelActions = new();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    parallelActions.Add(() => Compute(i));
}

Parallel.Invoke(parallelActions.ToArray());
```

I would like to stop the loop execution if it takes longer than `maxTime` seconds. Do you know how to end a parallel loop by immediately stopping execution?

I tried adding `CancellationToken`:

```cs
List<Action> parallelActions = new();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    parallelActions.Add(() => Compute(i));
}

using CancellationTokenSource cts = new(new TimeSpan(0, 0, maxTime));
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new() { CancellationToken = cts.Token };

Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions, parallelActions.ToArray());
```

The problem is that even if I add `CancellationToken`, already started `Compute` functions will not stop, so I have to wait a very long time for it to finish. How to change it?

**More info:** I am targeting the .NET 7 platform. Each individual `Compute` invocation takes dozens of minutes to complete on average.

Comment: Cancellation is *cooperative*, you can require it via `CancellationToken`, but you should add support on `Compute` side.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code of `Compute`. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't insist on cancellation, you can try `Parallel.For` instead of `Parallel.Invoke`

Comment: *"immediately stopping execution"* -- By immediately, do you mean to abort already started executions of the `Compute`? How much time does each `Compute` independently takes on average?

Comment: `By immediately, do you mean to abort already started executions of the Compute?` - Yes
`How much time does each Compute independently takes on average?` - dozens of minutes

Comment: Is it an option to run the `Parallel.Invoke` operation on a separate process, so that when the timeout is elapsed to kill the process? Also please mention in the question the .NET platform that you are targeting. Is it .NET 7 or .NET Framework?

Comment: A separate process would require building a separate executable, right?
I tried using `Parallel.Invoke` on a separate thread and then, after the time has elapsed using `thread.Abort()`, but this function is obsolete and throws an error on my platform (which is .NET 7)

Comment: Related: [Forcefully terminate thread generated by Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066319/forcefully-terminate-thread-generated-by-parallel-foreach).

Comment: Yes, a separate process would require to split your application into two executables. Could you share more information about the `Compute` method? Obviously it is not cancellable (it doesn't have a `CancellationToken` argument). Is it doing CPU-bound computations, or it does I/O-bound work like HTTP requests or DB queries? Does it induce any side-effects on the state of the application (`static` fields etc), that could cause state corruption in case the thread that executes the `Compute` is forcefully aborted in a non-cooperative fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567) for aborting forcefully work in a non-cooperative fashion, is to run the work on a separate executable and abort the work by killing the process. This is the only way to protect the state of you main executable from corruption. Even if you are targeting a .NET platform that supports the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) API, like the .NET Framework, by using it you risk the stability of your application and the correctness of its behavior.

.NET 7 has introduced the [`ControlledExecution.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.controlledexecution.run) method, that performs a controlled `Thread.Abort` without actually terminating the current thread. The termination is canceled automatically with the [`Thread.ResetAbort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.resetabort). Using the `ControlledExecution.Run` method generates a [compilation warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0046):

> The `ControlledExecution.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` method might corrupt the process, and should not be used in production code.

Although the `Thread.Abort` is "controlled", it can corrupt the state of your application just as easily as the raw `Thread.Abort`. The thread is aborted at any arbitrary moment while executing individual CPU instructions. Not methods, CPU instructions. Most .NET APIs are compiled to multiple CPU instructions, and are not hardened for recovering after a partial execution of their instruction set.

Assuming that you understand the risks, here is how you can use it:

```
using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    CancellationToken = cts.Token,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 // Configurable
};

ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out _, out int cpt);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism, cpt);

cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120));

Parallel.For(0, 1000, options, index =>
{
    ControlledExecution.Run(() =>
    {
        Compute(index);
    }, cts.Token);
});
```

In the above example the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) configures the `ThreadPool`, so that it creates immediately all the threads that the `Parallel.For` needs in order to reach its desirable degree of parallelism from the get-go. If you omit it, the `ThreadPool` might take some time before creating the required number of threads.

An alternative idea is to bypass the `ThreadPool` and instead use dedicated threads. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570579/is-it-possible-always-to-force-a-new-thread-with-task/68929857#68929857) a custom `TaskScheduler` that creates a dedicated background thread per task.

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation is *cooperative*, you can require it via `CancellationToken`, but you should add some support on the `Compute` side. Yet another problem is that, if you want to use cancellation, you should turn threads into `Task`s and switch to `async` / `await`, which can be difficult (it involves paradigm changing). As a quick fix, you can try `Parallel.For` which we can *break* (you don't cancel `Compute` but not start all `1000` of them):

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions() {
  // You can play with this parameter to tune the performance
  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount  
};

Parallel.For(0, 1000, options, (index, state) => {
  if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > maxTime) 
    state.Break(); // or state.Stop();
  else
    Compute(index);
});

sw.Stop();
```

Here we start some (ususally 4..16, depending on CPU) `Compute` in parallel, when some `Compute` finished we start another one etc. In case of timeout we just don't start other `Compute` execution(s) and leave the loop.

Comment: It should be noted that the [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) class is not documented of being thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, this allows you to break the loop faster, but in my case it is much slower than `Parallel.Invoke` (few times slower).

Comment: @CeD: You can play with `options` to tune the performance